# Accessing one-to-one table field value in Django

Tags: python, django, one-to-one

I have a Django model which creates a one-to-one-field relationship with Django sites

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class SiteSettings(models.Model):
    site = models.OneToOneField(Site, related_name="settings", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    header_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

I want to access the `header_text` field in the SiteSettings table from the Site model. I have tried getting the value using:

```
value = Site.settings.header_text
print(value)
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'ReverseOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute
> 'header_text'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `Site.objects.get().settings.header_text`

Comment: `Site` is not a `Site` object, but the `Site` calss.

Comment: Thank you @dmitryguzeev that worked. If you create an answer, I will mark it as accepted

Comment: @Rutnet: this works if you have *one* `Site` in the database. If there are multiple, that will raise an error, since `.get()` can not know what site to retrieve...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree, but in my use case I cannot use get_current_site because I am using django-tenants. Also I won't have more than one entry for site

Comment: @Rutnet: If you do not have multiple `Site`s, you need no `ForeignKey` to the `Site`, in that case, you simply construct a model with `header_text`, and then you access it with `SiteSettings.objects.get().header_text`. This thus means that your `SiteSettings` has *exactly one* records.

Comment: Yes I agree that under normal circumstances that is best, but I am extending a framework and I didn't want to touch the core models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Site` is a reference to the `Site` class, not a `Site` object. You can use [**`get_current()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.shortcuts.get_current_site) to obtain the current site and then use the relation in reverse:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

get_current().settings.header_text
```

If there are no multiple sites, it makes not much sense to work with a `ForeignKey` to `Site` in the first place, since there will only be one. In that case, you can make a model:

```
# if there are no multiple Sites
from django.db import models

class SiteSettings(models.Model):
    # no ForeignKey to Site
    header_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

then you make sure there is *exactly* one records for the `SiteSettings`, and you access it with:

```
# if there are no multiple Sites and only one SiteSettings record
SiteSettings.objects.get().header_text
```

you can slighly boost the performance by using [**`.only(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only):

```
# if there are no multiple Sites and only one SiteSettings record
SiteSettings.objects.only('header_text').get().header_text
```

Comment: I should add to this that "get_current()" worked aswell which is probably the better answer. The difference between "get_current()" and "get_current_site()" is that I don't have to pass the request for the first.

Comment: @Rutnet: yes, I made a mistake. Thanks